# Matplotlib + Pandas = how to see labels ?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to display a dataframe with long labels.
The plot is mainly occupied by the graphs, when I would like it to show the labels.
I have :

```
new_labels = []
for i, index in enumerate(df.index):
    new_label = "%s (%.2f)"%(index,df.performance[i])
    new_labels.append(new_label)

fig , axes = plt.subplots(1,1)
df.sort_values(col_name).plot(kind='barh', ax=axes)
axes.xaxis.set_ticklabels(new_labels)
axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
```

Which gives me : 
[image]

As you can see, the labels are not displayed.
Indeed there values is :

```
new_labels
['PLS regression\n\n    PLSRe (0.12)',
 'Regression based on k-nea (0.44)',
 'The Gaussian Process mode (0.46)',
 'Orthogonal Matching Pursu (0.52)',
 'An extremely randomized t (0.54)',
 'RANSAC (RANdom SAmple Con (0.56)',
 'Elastic Net model with it (0.66)',
 'Kernel ridge regression. (0.67)',
 'Cross-validated Orthogona (0.67)',
 'Linear Model trained with (0.68)',
 'Linear regression with co (0.68)',
 'Theil-Sen Estimator (0.68)',
 'Lasso linear model with i (0.69)',
 'Bayesian ridge regression (0.70)'...
```

How can I give more space to my labels, and have shorter bars ?

Comment: Why not increase the `figsize`? `plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add more space to the left side of the plot such that the labels have the chance to be shown completely. This can be done using

```
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.5)
```

where `0.5` means 50% of the figure width.

Complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['PLS regression PLSRe (0.12)',
 'Regression based on k-nea (0.44)',
 'The Gaussian Process mode (0.46)',
 'Orthogonal Matching Pursu (0.52)',
 'An extremely randomized t (0.54)',
 'RANSAC (RANdom SAmple Con (0.56)',
 'Elastic Net model with it (0.66)',
 'Kernel ridge regression. (0.67)',
 'Cross-validated Orthogona (0.67)',
 'Linear Model trained with (0.68)',
 'Linear regression with co (0.68)',
 'Theil-Sen Estimator (0.68)',
 'Lasso linear model with i (0.69)',
 'Bayesian ridge regression (0.70)']

values = [0.12, .44,.46,.52,.54,.56,.66,.67,.67,.68,.68,.68,.69,.7]

df = pd.DataFrame(values, index=labels)

fig , axes = plt.subplots(1,1)
fig.subplots_adjust(left=0.5)
df.plot(kind='barh', ax=axes)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df.sort_values(col_name).plot(x=new_labels, kind='barh', ax=axes)
#  NOTE:                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```